# How to install beamer theme `Irubataru/beamer-themes` to mac

Tags: latex, beamer

https://github.com/Irubataru/beamer-themes

In this Markdown...

> "Standard LaTeX installation, put the files somewhere LaTeX can find them. I normally put these in"

```
$TEXMFHOME/tex/latex/beamer/themes/
```

What "the files" stands for.

Comment: "the files" means all the files from the github repository, in particular all `.sty` files. For keeping things organized, you can leave them in their `inner`, `outer` etc folders and place the complete folders in this directory. You can download the whole repository as .zip file https://github.com/Irubataru/beamer-themes/archive/refs/heads/master.zip

Comment: I tried, but compiler failed.

``! LaTeX Error: File `beamerthemeLightTheme.sty' not found.``


$ pwd
``/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/themes`` 
$ ls
``color  font  inner  LICENSE  outer  README.md  theme`` 

I'was using lua latex.

Comment: `/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/` is not your texmfhome folder. Putting files there will mess with your latex distribution. Instead find out where your texmfhome folder is with `kpsewhich --var-value TEXMFHOME` and put the files there.

Comment: Compiler worked. Thank you.

$ kpsewhich --var-value TEXMFHOME
``/Users/<user name>/Library/texmf``

The files were putted like... 
``/Users/<user name>/Library/texmf/tex/latex/beamer/themes/beamer-themes-master``

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to copy all the files (in particular all the `.sty` files) from the github repository to your `TEXMFHOME` folder. To keep things organized, you can leave the files in their subfolders.

You can download them as `.zip` file form https://github.com/Irubataru/beamer-themes/archive/refs/heads/master.zip

---

To determine where your `TEXMFHOME` folder is, you can run

```
kpsewhich --var-value TEXMFHOME
```